# Is there a way to exclude a directory in AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, amazon-linux

We have an auto deployment from BitBucket set up to deploy to one of three EC2 instances. Everything currently works fine except our /data directory (which contains CMS-uploaded images, videos, etc) is not part of the repository. So during deployment, the existing /data directory on the specific instance is removed.

I see that it's possible to set exclusions for file ownership/group and permissions using the "exclude" parameter; however, no such parameter seems to exist for the Files section:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html

It seems as if this would be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet. Does anyone have any suggestions for excluding files for overwriting during a deployment?

The only thing I can come up with at this point is to manually specify each directory that is to be overridden as well as each root file in appspec.yml. That's far from ideal, as it would need to be edited each time a new directory or root file is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others are looking, the solution is to manually specify each directory and/or file via the appspec "files" directive. This way files not included in the list do not get deployed.

The appspec file will then need to be updated any time a new directory or root file is added.

Comment: We are looking for a way to do this as well now, hard to believe there is no way to exclude a pattern and instead having to include everything else and keep the structure up to date.  Seems like an essential feature to have to me to be able to exclude directories.

Comment: I agree. It's a real PITA, but we've gotten by with manually specifying each directory in the appspec file.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I face same problem. I need to exclude one file, but there are too many file in same directory and its hard to specify each file in appspec file. So I create two  script file to run before and after install hook.

`before_install.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /path/to/file/need/to/exclude/on/deployment /path/to/temp/directory/which/will/not/update/on/deploment
```

above script move file to location which will be not update in deployment.
`after_install.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /path/to/temp/excluded/file /path/to/file/exact/location
```

Above script place previous version of excluded file
Add below lines in appspec.yaml

```
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: /scripts/before_install.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: /scripts/after_install.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

You should structure your app's data outside of the deployment package.

Keeping app data in the same directory as deployment package is not a good approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't help in this circumstance. I've inherited a legacy application. And /data is not part of the repo anyway. It seems that the only way to do this at the moment is to specify each directory and/or root file.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to achieve this with the except property of the permissions section. Please see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-permissions.html.

Comment: The permissions "except" section provides overrides for file/directory ownership, but not for the inclusion of the file in deployment. The only solution I've found is to manually specify the specific files and directories that are to be included in the deployment.